# CRUD Operations in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, crud

I have to make a ASP.NET MVC 4 Page which contains Customer details.
One form I have to create in which I have to perform Customer Create, Update and Delete.
The different fields are..
1) Customer ID
2) Customer Name
3) Customer Image
4) Customer Address
Now, I am confused with Customer Image. How to store Image in database and how to display it in Gridview from database. Please solve my problem as it's very important for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LajosArpad said save image as file and only save path of the image in database.

Here is view for creating customer

```
<div class="box box-primary">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-horizontal box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
            </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Image</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control" name="image" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Customer customer, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var filePath = GetFilePath(image.FileName);
                image.SaveAs(filePath);
                customer.ImageUrl = "~/images/upload/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            }
            // Save customer to database
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(news);
    }

    // Get absolute path for saving image and check it does not exist
    public static string GetFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        var targetFolder = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/images/upload/");
        var targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
            name = name + "-" + (new Random()).Next();
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            name = name + extension;
            GetFilePath(name);
        }

        return targetPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You store the image as a file and you store the path of the image in the database. If I were you I would generate the filenames instead of using the original filenames to make sure they are not duplicated. So you do not need to store the images in the database, you can store them as separate files.